How can I solve this Semver dependencies problem in Ionic app?
I'm working on a Ionic app but whenever I run npm install I get the following error:
 semver  7.0.0 - 7.5.1
Severity: moderate
semver vulnerable to Regular Expression Denial of Service - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-c2qf-rxjj-qqgw
fix available via `npm audit fix`
node_modules/npm-watch/node_modules/simple-update-notifier/node_modules/semver
  simple-update-notifier  1.0.7 - 1.1.0
  Depends on vulnerable versions of semver
  node_modules/npm-watch/node_modules/simple-update-notifier
    nodemon  2.0.19 - 2.0.22
    Depends on vulnerable versions of simple-update-notifier

3 moderate severity vulnerabilities

I tried running npm audit fix and npm audit fix--force but the error persists. I also tried deleting package.lock.json and the node_modules folder and the running npm install again but to no avail.
I also tried to set "overrides": { "semver": "~7.5.3" } in the package.json but gave me conflicts with other dependencies.
This is my package.json:
  {
  "name": "testProject",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "author": "Ionic Framework",
  "homepage": "https://ionicframework.com/",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^18.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "^18.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^18.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^18.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^18.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^18.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^18.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^18.0.0",
    "@capacitor/splash-screen": "^6.0.0",
    "@ionic/angular": "^8.0.0",
    "ionicons": "^7.0.0",
    "rxjs": "~7.8.0",
    "semver": "^7.6.2",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.14.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^18.0.0",
    "@angular-eslint/builder": "^18.0.0",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^18.0.0",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin-template": "^18.0.0",
    "@angular-eslint/schematics": "^18.0.0",
    "@angular-eslint/template-parser": "^18.0.0",
    "@angular/cli": "^18.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^18.0.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^18.0.0",
    "@capacitor/assets": "^3.0.5",
    "@ionic/angular-toolkit": "^11.0.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "~5.1.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^6.0.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^6.0.0",
    "eslint": "^8.57.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.29.1",
    "eslint-plugin-jsdoc": "^48.2.1",
    "eslint-plugin-prefer-arrow": "1.2.2",
    "jasmine-core": "~5.1.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~6.4.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.2.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~5.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~2.1.0",
    "nodemon": "^3.1.3",
    "typescript": "~5.4.0"
  },
  "description": "An Ionic project"
}

What could be the problem? In general, how do you solve dependency problems? I'm pretty new to this sort of errors

sounds like an issue within your node/npm package install on your machine, I would uninstall and reinstall to see if that fixes the issue.
